# With jQuery, IE<9 fails appending bundle of elements with text node. Is this jQuery bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

With jQuery 1.11.3, I found elements are disordered in IE<9, when I append() a bundle of elements including text node. Is this jQuery bug, or mine?

Test Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery test</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div"></div>
        <script>
            $('#div').append(
                $('<span/>', {
                    css: {
                        color: 'red'
                    },
                    text: 'Some'
                }).add(
                    $(document.createTextNode(' Texts '))
                ).add(
                    $('<span/>', {
                        css: {
                            fontSize: 'x-large'
                        },
                        text: 'are'
                    })
                ).add(
                    $(document.createTextNode(' appended.'))
                )
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In IE 11 (and all other modern browsers):

[image: IE11]

In IE 8 emulation mode:

[image: IE8]

Comment: Rather than `$(..).append($(..).add(..).add(..).add(...))`, control the insertion order more directly with this; `$(...).append(...).append(...).append(...)`.  The first one relies on the DOM order inside the jQuery object after `.add()`.  It would be better to directly control the `.append()` order yourself.

Comment: @jfriend00: yes it "resolves" the situation, but I'm concerning whether this is jQuery bug and must be reported, since append()ing a bundle of elements together, especially when I play with vars, is more useful than append()ing elements each by each.

Comment: You can append mulitple elements just by using a comma separated list, there's no need for `add`, like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/yryr026w/

Comment: @adeneo: ugh thanks for advice. That helped my personal problem but still remains my chance for reporting bug for jQuery foundation... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a bug, but rather a documented jQuery behavior. Directly from the [doc for `.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/):

> Do not assume that this method appends the elements to the existing
>   collection in the order they are passed to the .add() method. When all elements 
>   are members of the same document, the resulting collection from .add()
>   will be sorted in document order; that is, in order of each element's
>   appearance in the document. If the collection consists of elements
>   from different documents **or ones not in any document, the sort order
>   is undefined**.

So, jQuery specifically documents that the order for your newly created DOM elements that are not in the DOM is undefined.

As I mentioned in my comment, you could control the `.append()` order yourself to avoid this issue by using this type of construct instead of `.add()`:

```
$(...).append(...).append(...).append(...)
```

The jQuery doc itself recommends:

```
$(array_of_DOM_elements)
```

So, you could collect the DOM elements into an array (rather than into a jQuery object) which would also be more efficient than multiple calls to `.add()` (each of which creates a new jQuery object) and then add that array to a jQuery object in one call.

You could also create your own document fragment, append the elements into the fragment, then insert the fragment.